# Remove lines from file if the first column appears in another file

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I have to files like this:

File1:

```
id1 junk junk junk 

id2 junk junk junk 

id3 junk junk junk 

id4 junk junk junk
```

File2:

```
id2

id3
```

How can I remove the 2 lines from File1 that has id in File2. So the output would be

```
id1 junk junk junk

id4 junk junk junk
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} !($1 in a)' file2 file1

id1 junk junk junk
id4 junk junk junk
```

Or using `grep -v` with process substitution:

```
grep -vf <(sed 's/.*/^&[[:blank:]]/' file2) file1

id1 junk junk junk
id4 junk junk junk
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. awk is so powerful.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell grep to exclude everything from file2

grep -vf file2 file1